# Is there a way to randomly select a cell based on weighted probability in Excel?

Tags: excel

Say there's a list of names:

```
Peter
Andrew
James
John
Philip
Thomas
Matthew
```

I want to select one name randomly, and the formulas I'm currently using to do this are `=RANDBETWEEN(1,7)` and `=VLOOKUP(A3,$A$6:$B$12,2)`.

However, is there a way to give each name a weight so that there is a higher chance for one particular name to be selected, because the only way I can think of doing that would be to add duplicate names to the list:

```
Peter
Peter
Peter
Peter
Peter
Andrew
Andrew
Andrew
James
James
John
Philip
Thomas
Thomas
Thomas
Thomas
Matthew
Mathhew
```

This way Peter would have the greatest probability of being randomly selected since the name appears the most, but I'd prefer not to do it this way if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Any response is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method requires no additional columns or helper cells.

Instead of `RANDBETWEEN(1,7)` use the following formula instead:

```
=CHOOSE(VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(0,99),{0,1;28,2;45,3;55,4;60,5;65,6;87,7},2,1),1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

That will give you a weighting approximately equal to your longer list.

Then go ahead and use your `=VLOOKUP(A3,$A$6:$B$12,2)` to return the name.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an additional left column near the names and add number which will imply your desired probability.

```
1   Peter 
10  Andrew
15  James
25  John
75  Philip
95  Thomas
100 Matthew
```

And now.. Use the `randbetween` 1 to 100 and instead of using the `vlookup` as false use it as true on match… this will give you the closet number to the round.

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,$A$6:$B$12,2,1)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about "instead of using the vlookup as false use it as true on match"... The only thing I changed was adding the numbers on the left column from 1-100 for each name respectively.

Comment: The 4th value in vlookup is for exact match (0 or  false) and for close value (1, or true) so, add on your function : =VLOOKUP(A3,$A$6:$B$12,2,1)

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to use a combination of RANDBETWEEN with INDEX and MATCH.

Using MATCH's last parameter which specifies the type of comparison to apply, you can effectively use ranges of values to match on (e.g. if < 50 do X, if 51 - 75 do Y if 76-100 do Z). This means that if you add an extra column next to your names and assign caps ceiling values to each, you will effectively be able to create weighted probabilities.

Try adding ceilings between 1-100 to all names and try the following:

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(RANDBETWEEN(1,100),B:B,1))
```

This is assuming your names are in A and your ceilings are in B.

Comment: What's an example of a ceiling, never used them before.

Comment: A ceiling is a high value. Let's say you have Peter, Andrew and James and you want to give them the probabilities 50%, 30% and 20% respectively. Set Peter to 50, Andrew to 80 and James to 100. Using the above formula will enable you to randomize with weighted probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same need and solved it using VBA.

In the following VBA code, simply state the names and the weights on line 2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    RandomName = WeightedRnd(Array("Peter", "Andrew", "James"), Array(34, 33, 33))
    MsgBox(RandomName)
End Sub

Function WeightedRnd(items As Variant, weights As Variant) As Variant
    Dim myItems(1 To 100) As Variant
    Dim weight As Variant
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim myNumber As Variant
    i = 1
    n = 0

    For Each weight In weights
        For p = 1 To weight
           myItems(i) = items(n)
           i = i + 1
        Next
        n = n + 1
    Next

    n = UBound(myItems) - LBound(myItems) + 1
    pick = getRandom(1, n)
    WeightedRnd = myItems(pick)
End Function

Function getRandom(lowerbound, upperbound)
    Randomize
    getRandom = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
End Function
```

NB: Make sure the sum of your weights is equal to 100 or to the upperbound of myItems array: `Dim myItems(1 To 100) As Variant`